# save the list of sub directories in path

Tags: php

I want to point to a folder and then the php script should take the list of sub directories from that folder and save it into the database

Can anyone provide a php script which would do the same
thanks in advance

```
$path = "new/cat1/";
```

want to get the list of sub-directories inside the $path folder 
and save those sub-directory names to database. No need to take the filename of filelist

Comment: This is an extremely hazy question. "A folder" where? On the server? The user's machine?

Comment: If you want to get information about a folder's contents, you could have a look at the php documentation for `opendir()`. Example #1 seems to do what you want. http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.opendir.php

Answer (score 1):

PHP  5's new [RecursiveDirectoryIterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php) is the way to go. It's a bit complicated to get into at first but makes things very easy. The User Contributed Notes provide some good examples.

You would have to walk through your directory structure and use `is_dir()` on each entry (use `->key()` to get the full path) to find out whether it's a directory.